# openssh asks for dsa

Tags: linux, ssh, ssh-keys

Today, when I tried to login from my Linux laptop to a Linux server with SSH, I got the error message:

> WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!

As I did not change the machines keys I did an `ssh -v` to see what happens. I found that my OpenSSH client (SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2) accepts the "host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256", while in my known_hosts there is a `rsa-key` for the corresponding server (which worked fine till today...).

The only thing that might have changed is the OpenSSH version.

How can I make OpenSSH ask for the RSA host key again?

P.S.: The Error Message and some preceding lines as requested:

```
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:k/ADO4oeYIUNdsGBEkKXkggNP5pr3t9QlYSr8GOLSd1
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!
It is also possible that a host key has just been changed.
The fingerprint for the ECDSA key sent by the remote host is
SHA256:k/ADO4oeYIUNdsGBEkKXkggNP5pr3t9QlYSr8GOLSd1.
Please contact your system administrator.
Add correct host key in /home/nn/.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this message.
Offending RSA key in /home/nn/.ssh/known_hosts:51
  remove with:
  ssh-keygen -f "/home/nn/.ssh/known_hosts" -R server31
ECDSA host key for server31 has changed and you have requested strict checking.
Host key verification failed.
```

Comment: please, provide the whole error message, you got.

Comment: @Jakuje : Thanks, could not put the message into a comment... Please see my original post. When I use keyscan ( `ssh-keyscan -t rsa server31` ) I can see that the rsa key equals the one in my known_hosts.

Answer (score 1):

You can request a specific host key algorithm with `HostKeyAlgorithms` option. In CLI for RSA:

```
ssh -o HostKeyAlgorithms=ssh-rsa <server>
```

or in the `~/.ssh/config` under the specific `Host` section:

```
HostKeyAlgorithms=ssh-rsa
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this shows, that my idea was wrong...   With that I get an DNS-Spoofing warning: "WARNING: POSSIBLE DNS SPOOFING DETECTED! The RSA host key has changed, and the key for the corresponding IP address is unchanged" . Now I am totally lost. The IP address and the keys definitly did not change.